# Google Adsense is not visible

Tags: adsense

I inserted Google Adsense code to my site, I received mail from Google that all is ok and that adv will work after some hours. but it's third day that it 's not showen. I looked at the browser code and saw that at the script code is written *style="display: none; visibility: hidden; "*

Why? How can I fix it? What is wrong, can anyone help me?

Comment: How many adds you are trying to display? More than 3 ads canto do displayed in a single page and also check the status of the ads in the adsense portal. Check whether it is in new or active state. Only active ads will be displayed.

Comment: 1. In control panel I had not switched the publication of the ads on, now I switched and wait. The state is active in green color

Comment: Is your ads visible now? Is it showing active in the ads list? If show it should work.

Comment: Yes, it is active but not visible yet:( It almost show page hits in report, and zero clicks

Comment: I found the cause. It was due to AdBlock on my browsers )))

Answer (score -1):

1. sometimes not relevant ads with price quote is available ads not shown, but try in other links of same website it will works
2. remove adblocking softwares and widgets of browsers
3. may be ads was block due to rules violation
4. check browser supports adobe flash