# Google adsense: Ads are not displaying

Tags: adsense

Here is my ad code.

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-5069923452283264"
     data-ad-slot="4908017235"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

In browse console getting 400 get error

```
show_ads_impl.js:513 GET https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-88026572198556…=0&fu=144&bc=1&ifi=1&xpc=ZmUO9SGcPe&p=http%3A//www.shadiportal.com&dtd=281 403 ()iv @ show_ads_impl.js:513rv @ show_ads_impl.js:519Sw @ show_ads_impl.js:548Mt @ show_ads_impl.js:551bv @ show_ads_impl.js:511f.ap @ show_ads_impl.js:60bi @ show_ads_impl.js:62(anonymous function) @ show_ads_impl.js:555(anonymous function) @ show_ads_impl.js:555
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Adsense won't allow for matrimonial (Dating) category websites.

Answer (score -3):

1. sometimes not relevant ads with price quote is available ads not shown, but try in other links of same website it will works
2. remove adblocking softwares and widgets of browsers
3. may be ads was block due to rules violation
4. check browser supports adobe flash

Comment: [Please don't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/248627) repeat [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31839300/354577) and please read [answer]. At _best_ this should be a comment.